# Reducing sampling in simulation

Tags: modelica, openmodelica

Is there any way in Modelica, to reduce the sampeling during simulations? I have a DCDC converter with high frequency, consequently generating huge dataset. I am wondering, if there is any way to reduce the size of the dataset during simulation/exportation?
Thanks

Trying to create smaller dataset from models that generate huge ones (models with high frequencies).

Answer (score 1):

Basically when you simulate, do not press the -> press the S on the toolbar and you get several tabs and the ones you care about are General and Output.

In General you can specify the number of intervals to reduce the data stored. It will only be stored at each interval.

In the Output you can say not to store events for example. You can also filter out variables that you are not interested in to reduce the result file size. Note that "Equidistant Time Grid" is activated by default, if not this would generate quite a lot of output maybe even several times per interval.

See more here about the things you have in General/Output:
https://openmodelica.org/doc/OpenModelicaUsersGuide/1.20/omedit.html#simulating-a-model

Comment: What I understand the Modelica specification does not describe much about sampling of the solution, correct me if I am wrong. The possibility to"reduction of sampling points" for continuous time models is more controlled in the software tool you use, i.e. OpenModelica, Dymola etc or FMU.  If you use FMU there is a standardization of how you control the sampling.  One parameter is "ncp"  and stands for number of communications points and is simply how many equally distant data points you want.  Here is perhaps some options related to filtering of event that Adrian talked about, but not sure.

Comment: Is there any chance that a some models might confuse the simulation and despite the fact that number of intervals is set to 1000, when I export the csv, it still contains more than 7000 lines? For some models, this works, and for some, it doesn't so I am very confused about that.

Comment: Do you use OpenModelica and Aldo run the simulations there? Or do you possibly export FMUs and run in Python ( or even Julia)? It would help us if you describe the software you use.

Comment: I am using OpenModelica 1.18.1, no FMU

Comment: Is it possible that there is a minimal interval size for certain simulations? If I set interval to a very small value (0.01), the sampling is now consistent. Any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

By including our desired variables in the `Variable Filter` in `Output` tab one can reduce the size of the output file **without compromising** the interval points. Each entry follows a POSIX EXTENDED regular expression format, say:
for a list of x,y,z it is ^x|y|z$. Another best practice could be unchecking the flag `Store variables at Events`. The best answer for this question is already answered by Adrian Pop.

[image: OpenModelica view for variable filters]